# How to optimize a DB call existing under a FOR loop (platform: Django, Python, Postgres)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, query-optimization

I'm optimizing a Django website I maintain, for performance. Among other things, I've made the mistake of including non-trivial db calls under a FOR loop. Much better practice would be to make the DB call once, and then loop over the data as much as I want. How can I accomplish that in the following piece of code? Need a protip here!

```
link_ids = [link.id for link in context["object_list"]]
seen_replies = Publicreply.objects.filter(answer_to_id__in=link_ids,publicreply_seen_related__seen_user = user)
for link in context["object_list"]:
        try:
            latest_reply = link.publicreply_set.latest('submitted_on')
            if latest_reply in seen_replies:
               #do something
        except:
            pass
```

Essentially, profiling tells me that the line `latest_reply = link.publicreply_set.latest('submitted_on')` is adding significant overhead because it's doing a ton of DB queries (being under the FOR loop and all).

I can't seem to figure out a nice, clean way to move the call to outside the loop, and then process it's constituents within it. Anyone got any ideas?

**Note:** `link.publicreply_set.latest('submitted_on')` may yield `DoesNotExist`. I am on Postgres in production, but SQLite locally.

---

Models are:

```
class Link(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(500)])
    submitter = models.ForeignKey(User)
    submitted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Publicreply(models.Model):
    submitted_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    answer_to = models.ForeignKey(Link)
    submitted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    description = models.TextField(validators=[MaxLengthValidator(250)])

class Seen(models.Model):
    seen_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    seen_user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    seen_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    which_reply = models.ForeignKey(Publicreply, related_name="publicreply_seen_related")
```

Comment: @e4c5: added the models. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of [postgresql window function first_value](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html). This is an approach how you can improve performance:

```
link_ids = [link.id for link in context["object_list"]]
seen_replies = (   Publicreply
                   .objects
                   .filter(answer_to_id__in=link_ids,
                           publicreply_seen_related__seen_user = user)
                   )

latest_replies = dict ( seen_replies
                       .extra( 
                         select={ 
                            "id_latest_reply": 
                            """first_value(id) over 
                                  (partition by answer_to_id 
                                   order by submitted_on desc)
                            """ } )
                        .order_by()
                        .values_list( 'answer_to_id', 'id' )                        
                        .distinct()
                       )

for link in context["object_list"]:
        try:
            if link.id in latest_replies:
               last_replie= (Publicreply
                            .objects
                            .get(id=latest_reply[link.id])
                            )
               #do something
        except:
            pass
```

Comment: To clarify, this isn't database agnostic right, so for instance I locally have SQLite installed - I won't be able to test this in my local environment?

Comment: Of course. You tagged question as postgesql and no mention about agnostic approach. Also, most important, you tagged question as query-optimization, read about what means this tag. Post a new question with your new requirements.

Comment: My production environment is indeed Postgres, but I at least need to be able to test the solution locally before deploying it directly, don't you think?

Comment: I suppose it's high time I install postgres in my local environment too then

Comment: Your Q is about sql query optimization, my A is about it. I have not more comments, sorry. If you are wrong with your Q post a new one with right tags and requirements. Happy weekend ;)

Comment: Once I test this locally with Postgres, I'll be able to tell whether your 'A' is correct.  I'm about to do that.